How to calculate the value at risk for a spherical distribution?
I want to calculate for a spherical random variable $Y \sim S_d({\psi})$ (here $\psi$ is the characteristic generator) the value of $\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha(Y_1)$, i.e. the value at risk of the first component of $Y$. In particular I want to show for $\alpha \in [1/2, 1)$ that
$$
\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha(Y_1) \geq 0,
$$
with equality iff $\alpha = 1/2$.
My attempt: I know that I can write $Y = RS$ where the random variables $R$ and $S$ satisfy $R \geq 0$, $S \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \|x\|_2 = 1\})$ and $S$ and $R$ are independent. Now for $\epsilon > 0$ I have
$$
P[Y_1 \leq - \epsilon] = \int_{[0,\infty)} P[rS_1 \leq -\epsilon | R = r] F_R(dr) = \int_{(0,\infty)} P[S_1 \leq -\frac\epsilon r ] F_R(dr)
$$
Since $S \sim \mathrm{Unit}(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \|x\|_2 = 1\})$ I must have $P[S_1 \leq -\epsilon /r] < 1/2$ for all $r > 0$. Hence $P[Y_1 \leq - \epsilon] < 1/2$ which implies $\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha(Y_1) \geq 0$.
Finally note (some argument as above but for $\epsilon = 0$)
$$
P[Y_1 \leq 0] = P[S_1 \leq 0] = 1/2
$$
which means $\mathrm{VaR}_\alpha(Y_1) = 0$ iff $\alpha = 1/2$.
Question: Is my attempt correct (I cannot find any mistakes)? And is there possibly an easy way to immediately conclude the result? The assertion seems intuitive to me so there might be something I am missing.
Thanks in advance!
Edit: I suppose that equality iff $\alpha = 1/2$ is not correct. Simply take $Y \equiv 0$ to have $\mathrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(Y_1) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in (1/2,1)$.
